# Android ListFragment overlapping

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listfragment

I'm learning android development and I'm stuck in `Fragments`. I've read the tutorials point book and some android developers docs, so the next step is to build an app for my cell phone.

I'm trying to make a shopping list. When you start the app, a menu displays, it shows three options, the problematic one is the third one.

The idea is to allow the user to create update and remove products from that list.

So this's what I have done so far

**product_crud.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="116dp">

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name_txt"
    android:hint="@string/product_name"
    android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:text="@string/add_product"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_txt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**crudrowlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="10px"
>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
    android:text="@string/remove_product"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_name"
    android:textSize="40px"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_delete"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_delete" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

**PM_List_Fragment**

```
public class PM_List_Fragment extends ListFragment {

ProductsDataSource products;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    products = new ProductsDataSource(getActivity());
    try {
        products.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    CrudArrayAdapter crudArrayAdapter = new CrudArrayAdapter(getActivity(),products.getAllProducts());
    products.close();
    setListAdapter(crudArrayAdapter);
}
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class CrudArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

private final List<Product> list;
private final Activity context;

static class ViewHolder{
    protected TextView name;
    protected Button delete;
}


public CrudArrayAdapter(Activity context,List<Product> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout,list);
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    View view;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crudrowlayout,null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        viewHolder.delete = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        view = convertView;
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    return view;
}


}
```

and my **activity**

```
public class CrudProducts extends ListActivity {

private String msg = "Android: ";
private ProductsDataSource productsDataSource;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_crud);

    PM_List_Fragment pm_list_fragment = new PM_List_Fragment();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content,pm_list_fragment);

    Button btn_add = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //create a form or put some input text so we can update the db!
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
            if(editText.getText().length() > 0 && !productsDataSource.exists(editText.getText().toString())){
                Product prod = productsDataSource.createProduct(editText.getText().toString());
             //   adapter.add(prod);

            }else{
            if(editText.getText().length() == 0 )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please insert a name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This product already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
          //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

}
```

Don't worry about the datasource or the adapter, the problem here is that the `ListView` overlaps with the `EditText` and the `Button` *(deleteBtn)*. 
The Listview displays above the `EditText` and `Button`. I've tried to change the layouts in different ways but none of them worked.

I've read that you can implement this same functionality with a normal activity and a `ListView`, but I would like to learn how to do it this way.

Some ideas?

A picture of the problem:

[image: Problem overlap]

Comment: Please only post the relevant code/layout.  It is very confusing for the reader to scan through multiple files just find the relevant one.

Comment: Hi, Your problem is in fragment manager. Try to replace `add()` fragment with `replace()` method. Like: `transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit(); `  [http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a few things I noticed which might help you!

Firstly, `CrudProducts extends ListActivity` and `PM_List_Fragment extends ListFragment`. If your intention is to show a list you should rely on `ListFragment` only. You could make `CrudProducts` extend simply an `Activity`.

If you do so, you could have below layout set for `CrudProducts` using `setContentView(R.layout.crud_activity)`

**crud_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Secondly, in your fragment `PM_List_Fragment` add

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_crud, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Thirdly, **product_crud.xml** also needs some refinement

You don't need below attributes for your `<ListView>` as parent of `ListView` is not a RelativeLayout

```
android:layout_below="@+id/btn_add"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Also you don't need in your childs of `RelativeLayout`

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Instead try to make your `Button` to `match_parent`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Also try balanced padding for your `Button` in `dp`

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
```

Above should fix your issues and list should be visible properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your main view is LinearLayout, try changing it to RelativeLayout.
You should try it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/buttonView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_txt"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
          />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

which will result in this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, and in the design view it looks exactly like this, However it's not working.
I've added a picture of the problem in my question.